# MongoDB Aggregation General Summation and Summation By Unique Keys

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have a collection of objects in a document for sold cars from a dealership:

```
{
 id: 'randomId',
 model: 'Jetta'
 carId: 'randomId',
 salesmanId: 'salesmenId3'
},
{
 id: 'randomId',
 model: 'Civic'
 carId: 'randomId',
 salesmanId: 'salesmenId2'
},
{
 id: 'randomId',
 model: 'Civic'
 carId: 'randomId',
 salesmanId: 'salesmenId2'
},
{
 id: 'randomId',
 model: 'S200'
 carId: 'randomId',
 salesmanId: 'salesmenId'
},
{
 id: 'randomId',
 model: 'Jetta'
 carId: 'randomId',
 salesmanId: 'salesmenId3'
},
{
 id: 'randomId',
 model: 'Civic'
 carId: 'randomId',
 salesmanId: 'salesmenId2'
},
...
```

I'd like to be able to query the total cars per salesmanId and the total unique car models per salesmanId.

For example if I matched by 'salesmenId2', I'd like this to be returned:

```
{
 salesmanId: 'salesmenId2',
 totalCars: 3,
 totalUniqueCars: 1
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$match: {'salesmanId':  'salesmenId2' },
      {
          $group: {
            _id: '$salesmanId',
            uniqueCars: { $addToSet: '$model'},
            totalCars: { $sum: 1 }
          }
      },
      {
          $unwind:"$uniqueCars"
      },
      {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            totalUniqueCars: { $sum:1}
          }
      }
```

Which only returns the total unique cars right now. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You don't even have to use `$unwind`, Instead you can use [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator on the "uniqueCars" array field, which actually gives you the size of the array.

```
 db.cars.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "salesmanId":  "salesmenId2" } 
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
                    _id: "$salesmanId",
                    uniqueCars: { $addToSet: "$model"},
                    totalCars: { $sum: 1 }
                }
    },
    { 
       $project : { 
                     _id : 1, 
                     totalCars : 1, 
                     uniqueCar : { $size : "$uniqueCars" }
                  }
    }
 ])
```